# Solve recurrence relation using Master's method -> T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n^2 when n is even and T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n^3 when n is odd

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, recurrence, master-theorem

`T(n) ={ 2T(n/2) + n^2 when n is even and T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n^3 when n is odd`

I solved this separately and i am getting the solution as `theta(n^2)` if n is even and `theta(n^3)` if n is odd from case 3 of master's theorem. But i am not supposed to solve this problem separately.

How to solve a recurrence relation like this together?

`T(n) ={ 2T(n/2) + n^2 when n is even and T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n^3 when n is odd`

Is it solvable by master's theorem or master's theorem does not apply?

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: combine them into one relation. you will get something like n^3 + (n-1)^2 as the cost of the current step. What you see then?

Comment: Hint: look at the bit pattern of `n`.

Comment: you should say = T(n) ={ 2T(**floor**(n/2)) + n^2 when n is even and T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n^3 when n is odd, or something else.

Comment: @kelalaka you meant floor to be in the odd part, probably.

Comment: @Yola. Your solution is not complete. because on odd at the end will make it cubic?

Comment: @kelalaka yes, sure if it n = 3 and T(3) is a base case then it might not be cubic. I just thought that it is obvious and wanted answer to be smaller. But you are right!

Comment: @Yola The answer really depends on the input size with the floor function

Comment: I meant that you need to put floor in the part when `n` is odd not even.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `n = 2^k` for some integer `k`, so `n` equals to `100...00`. Then you can apply master method the even part of the recurrence. and obtain `theta(n^2)`.

Now suppose there is also `1` not in the most significant bit, e.g. `100100..00`. So, you will have at least one level in your recursion-tree all nodes of which add up to `n^3 * constant`, and by this you obtain `theta(n^3)`.

Thus, the answer is `theta(n^2)` if `n` is a power of two and `theta(n^3)` otherwise. But if we first encounter odd `n` and it is equal to a base case then it might not be cubic.

---

After some chatting with kelalaka it came to me that if first `1` is `k`-th from the right in `n` then if `k > (2/3)(1/lg 2)lg n`, we don't care any more about `(n/2^k)^3`. It is still `O(n^2)`.

Comment: let say that there are l even k odd where l+k = n. When it will be n^2 and when n^3. It seems quite complex from here.

Comment: @kelalaka Looks like if `l` is even and `k` is odd then `n` is odd, so we have `+ n^3`, which leads us to `O(n^3)`. Doesn't matter what happens on the next levels.

Comment: 3*2^n, all even only one odd

Comment: Let `m` be `8`, so `n = 3*m^2 = 24`. In binary it is `11000`. Three times you can divide it and eventually you get `n/8`, it is odd, so you apply the rule for odd, which is `T(n/8) = T(n/16) + (n/8)^3 = T(..) + n^3/8^3`, well it is kinda `O(n^3)`. But we can also see it as `n^3/(n/3)^3 = 27`, so `O(n^3)` isn't a tight bound. Probably we need to take into account position least significant `1` in binary representation of `n`.

Comment: That is definitely when `O(n^3)` is a tight bound. We get `+n^3` on the first step.

Comment: so when yo say it is n^2 or n^3

Comment: if the first `1` is `k`-th from the right, then if `k > (2/3)(1/lg 2)lg n`, we don't care any more about `(n/2^k)^3`. It is still `O(n^2)`.